# Как подключить WebHook Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Я использую сервис по оплате с помощью криптовалют https://0xprocessing.com/

В нем есть WebHook
И я хочу подключить это WebHook себе но я не могу его подключить
Делаю все в Django REST API мой код выглядит так

([Вот тут](https://webhook.site/#!/46819d64-6758-423e-9955-b9809207e0c4/d18bf527-20fd-4b62-8602-b89c58d79ceb/1) сервис по подключениям WebHook работает отлично все приходит)

`models.py`

```
class WebHook(models.Model):
    WebHook = models.JSONField(verbose_name='WebHook')
```

`serializers.py`

```
class WebHookInfo(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = "__all__"
        model = WebHook
```

`views.py`

```
class WebHookList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = WebHook.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WebHookInfo
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
```

`urls.py`

```
    path('pay/webhook/',WebHookList.as_view(), name='webhook'),
```

Что тут не так и что я могу сделать?